# MySQL/PHP that determines which week a day resides on for calendar use

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do the following:

If a user chooses a certain day, say June 21, 2010 we will repeat an event every 3rd monday of every month, but if they choose June 28, 2010 the event will repeat every last monday of every month. This is how google calendar does it, and I'm trying to repeat that functionality.

So basically I see it working something like this:
Given a date, get the week it exists in, and the day it is on. (1st week, 2nd week, 3rd week, 4th week, and last week.) Obviously sometimes 4th week will be the last week, and if that is the case I'd like to default to last week.

so in psuedocode:

```
$repeatweek = getweeknumber($date);
$repeatday = date('l', strtotime($date));


$todaysweek = getweeknumber($todaysdate);
$todayday =  date('l', strtotime($todaysdate));

if($todayday == $repeatday && $repeatweek == $todaysweek){
    echo "This is the day";
}
```

So the trick I guess is to properly define the getweeknumber() function, which I'm having a heck of time with. Especially determining first and last weeks.

Comment: June 21st 2010 is the third monday of June.  PHP's date() and strtotime() functions are very powerful for this kind of thing, but I don't think you'll get more specific answers unless you can better define your business logic.

Comment: @timedev: fixed. as far as the business logic it's fairly straightforward. Chose a day, repeat monthly on that day of the week for every month. First monday, repeat first monday. 2nd Tuesday, repeat 2nd tuesday.

Comment: what if's the 5th monday and the next month doesn't have one?

Comment: @artefacto, that's why on the last monday (whether it's 4 or 5), it repeats on the last monday and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`DatePeriod` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

Example:

```
<?php
$start = new DateTime("June 21, 2010");
$end = new DateTime("December 31, 2010");

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('fourth monday of next month');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

foreach ($period as $p) {
    echo $p->format("Y-m-d"), "\n";
}
```

gives

```
2010-07-26
2010-08-23
2010-09-27
2010-10-25
2010-11-22
2010-12-27
```

Comment: that looks promising, but I guess the issue would be how do I take a given date, and print on the string "fouth monday of next month" The documentation on DateInterval is pretty sparse.

Comment: The part "monday" is easy to get – just do `$start->format("l")`. For the first, second, etc., the best way would probably be to loop in one-week intervals to see how many mondays are in the month before and next. The documentation for the intervals is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: hmm, also i'm stuck using php 5.2.x, these features only work on 5.3.x